# PHP mail wont send to exchange or google apps account

Tags: php, email, html-email, contact-form

I am trying to diagnose an email issue with a php mail() function. The form is hosted on a 1 and 1 dedicated server, with site1.com (the site the script is hosted on and site 2 (our site). site1.com uses an exchange server to manage it's emails and our site (site2.com) uses Google Apps.

The mail form will not send to site1.com or site2.com, but it will send to my personal gmail account with no affliations to site1.com or site2.com. Has anyone got any ideas?

Here is the mail code:

```
if(isset($_POST["submit_contact"]))
{
// Set submitted variable
$submitted = TRUE;

// Get data and add to variables

$m_name = mysql_real_escape_string($_POST["name"]);
$m_email = mysql_real_escape_string($_POST["email"]);
$m_company = mysql_real_escape_string($_POST["company"]);
$m_phone = mysql_real_escape_string($_POST["phone"]);
$m_enquiry = mysql_real_escape_string($_POST["enquiry"]);
$dateadded = gmdate("Y-m-d H:i:s");
$ip = $_SERVER['REMOTE_ADDR'];
$type = "Website Submission";


    /// Set error messages ///

    $emailError = "Sorry this e-mail is not valid, please try again.";

    ///////////SECURITY CHECKS///////////////////

    /// Check E-mail Authenticity ///
    if(!preg_match('#^[a-z0-9.!\#$%&\'*+-/=?^_`{|}~]+@([0-9.]+|([^\s]+\.+[a-z]{2,6}))$#si', $m_email)) {
        $message = $emailError;
        $error = TRUE;
    }

    // Set email message //
    $errorMessage = "Sorry, you cannot add URLS in this contact form";
    /// Check for urls ///
    if(preg_match("/http/i", "$m_name")) { $message = $errorMessage; $error = TRUE; }
    if(preg_match("/http/i", "$m_email")) { $message = $errorMessage; $error = TRUE; }
    if(preg_match("/http/i", "$m_company")) { $message = $errorMessage; $error = TRUE; }
    if(preg_match("/http/i", "$m_phone")) { $message = $errorMessage; $error = TRUE; }
    if(preg_match("/http/i", "$m_enquiry")) { $message = $errorMessage; $error = TRUE; }

    //// END SECURITY CHECKS ////

    if(!$error) {

        /// Send E-Mail ///
        $em_to = "enquiries@site1.com,me@site2.com,me@gmail.com";
        $em_subject = "Website Contact Form Submission";
        $em_message = "
        <strong>Name:</strong> $m_name<br />
        <strong>Email:</strong> $m_email<br />
        <strong>Phone:</strong> $m_phone<br />";

        if(isset($_POST["callSub"])) 
        {
            $em_message .= "<strong>Time to call:</strong> $m_enquiry<br />";
        } else {
            $em_message .= "<strong>Company:</strong> $m_company<br />
                            <strong>Message:</strong> $m_enquiry<br />";
        }

        $em_message .= "<br /><br />

        <strong>Date Submitted:</strong> $dateadded<br />
        <strong>IP Address:</strong> $ip<br />";

        $headers  = 'MIME-Version: 1.0' . "\r\n";
        $headers .= 'Content-type: text/html; charset=iso-8859-1' . "\r\n";
        $headers .= 'From: "site1" <'.$m_email.'>\r\n';

        if(mail($em_to, $em_subject, $em_message, $headers)) {
            $error = FALSE;
            $message = "<h3>Thank you for your enquiry, we'll be in touch soon!</h3>";
        } else {
            $error = TRUE;
            $message = "Sorry there was an error processing the form. Please go back and try again.";
        }
```

Comment: The script works. If those accounts aren't getting those emails something in the middle is your problem. You need to figure out what that is and address those issues.

Comment: How would I go about doing that?

Comment: See if the maillog gives you anything

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it is about email deliverability, not about programming.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It was sending mail internally. I found [how to turn this off on my server](http://abundantdesigns.com/2012/10/10/deactivating-mail-on-a-domain-in-plesk/) and it solved the issue.